# How to change adobe flash player cache location in home directory?

Tags: flash, home-directory

Default location is ~/.adobe/Flash_Player/AssetCache but I would like to move it to ~/.cache

Comment: @Eliah, I would like to put the cache inside ~/.cache/ for example: ~/.cache/adobe/Flash_Player

Comment: In that case, [mutzmatron's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/172720/22949) below may do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Would creating a symlink suffice? I.e.

```
ln -s ~/.adobe/Flash_Player/AssetCache ~/.cache/AssetCache
```

**Note** this still stores the data at the original location and the symlink is at ~/.cache. You can also do the reverse if you first move the cache (make sure flash is closed when you do this):

```
mv ~/.adobe/Flash_Player/AssetCache ~/.cache/
ln -s ~/.cache/AssetCache ~/.adobe/Flash_Player/AssetCache
```

Also as Eliah Kagan pointed out as ~/.cache already exists, it's better to place the adobe cache *inside* this location if desired.

I'm not sure whether adobe will let you change this setting - I've never come across this option anywhere.

Comment: Hello @mutzmatron, my preferred solution is of course without symbolic links to ~/.adobe. :-)

Comment: @karolszk: Agreed - but that or the reverse may be your only option - I've posted it here as an answer as a _workaround_ for the case that. A better answer may not be not available.

Comment: thanks! Probably Adobe know nothing about $XDG_CACHE_HOME.. :-(

Comment: I would love a solution _without_ a symlink. Is there any environment variable that could be set?